# Optional parameters in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, email, nodemailer

I'm trying to do a email sender with all components, from, to, subject, textBody and etc..., but I don't know how to set optional parameters in express.js, I have already searched for some different stackoverflow questions but none answers to my question, see here my code:

```
//Here I have doubts 
app.get(`/from=:from&to=:to&subject=:subject?&textBody=:textBody?&htmlBody=:htmlBody?&cc=:cc?&bcc=:bcc?&attachments=:attachments?`, (req, res) => {

  const from = req.params.from;
  const to = req.params.to;
  const subject = req.params.subject;
  const textBody = req.params.textBody;
  const htmlBody = req.params.htmlBody;
  const cc = req.params.cc;
  const bcc = req.params.bcc;
  const attachments = req.query.attachments;

//code goes here...

})
```

Please help me.
I will appreciate your answers

Comment: Are you trying to write [route parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params)  or [query string parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query) (because you've mixing up the syntax of the two)

Comment: It's not documented because it is obvious to anyone who have written any code in any programming language. You use `if` -- `let subject = req.params.subject; if (subject === undefined) {subject = 'default value of subject}`. Since you can use `if` it also means you can use the ternary operator: `const subject = req.params.subject !== undefined ? req.params.subject : 'default value of subject'`. Parameters not sent to the server are simply `undefined`. Handle the `undefined` value in your code if you want to allow them to be `undefined` (optional)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `?` to make params optional. Update your route as this by adding `?`. `undefined` will be value if no value supplied in associated `param`. For example if `subject` is not supplied  `req.params.subject` will be `undefined` you can add your logic to have desired / default value to subject field,

```
app.get(
  `/api/sendemail/:from?/:to?/:subject?/:textBody?/:htmlBody?/:cc?/:bcc/:attachments?`,
  (req, res) => {
    const from = req.params.from;
    const to = req.params.to;
    const subject = req.params.subject ? req.params.subject : '';
    const textBody = req.params.textBody;
    const htmlBody = req.params.htmlBody;
    const cc = req.params.cc;
    const bcc = req.params.bcc;
    const attachments = req.query.attachments;

    //code goes here...
  }
);
```